# Need help understanding Booleans (setting and use)

Tags: java, set, boolean

I do not understand how to set multiple boolean values in a single if statement, nor am I certain if this is possible. I attempted to write out simple test code to experiment and found that I was confusing myself more.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

boolean t = false;
boolean f = false;
boolean a = false;

System.out.println("Enter T or F");
Scanner scan  = new Scanner(System.in);
String t_f = scan.nextLine();

if(t_f == "t"){
     t = true;
     a =false;
}
else if(t_f == "f"){
    f = true;
    a  = true;
}

if(t = true){
    System.out.println("true");
}
else if (f = true){
    System.out.println("false");
}
else if(a = true){
    System.out.println("test");
}
```

I am finding that if I enter 'f', "true" is printed, which shouldn't be happening as I've set it  to print false if 'f' is entered. (for example) I've attempted to manipulate the if statements varying the use of 'else if' and 'if' however I have had no success. Clearly I am missing a fundamental concept here, if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `str1.equals(str2)` to compare `String`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str1.equals(str2)` [to compare `String`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

```
if (t_f.equals("t"))
```

**Remember** that `=` is the assignment operator. You should use `==` to compare primitive types (`int`, `boolean`, `float`, `double`, ...). But since `if` statement expects a boolean as condition, you can simple use this:

```
if (t) // if (t == true)
...
if (!t) // if (t == false)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use  `==` for `boolean` comparison(or for primitive date types). `=` is the assignment operator.

```
if(t == true){
```

Also, since its `boolean`, you don't need to compare as well.

```
if(t){ // if requires a boolean so just using the boolean variable would do
```

And use `equals()` method for String comparisons. `==` with Strings compares the object references.

```
if(t_f.equals("t")){
```

Comment: -1 it's not a boolean - it's a string.

Comment: @alfasin: You're looking at the wrong part of the code. There are multiple bugs.

Comment: @alfasin - Check the edited answer. `t` is boolean. And `t_f` is `String`.

Comment: +1 Yeps, you are correct.

Comment: After changing it to `if(t)` (as well as the rest) my program terminates without printing out anything?

Comment: @user3274070: You need to fix the other bug, too. The one with the string comparisons.

Comment: @user3274070 - Make both the changes and give either "t" or "f" as the input. You'll see that it prints true or false accordingly.

Comment: Oh whoops...silly errors in both cases. Thank you!

Comment: for string comparison against constants put that constant value first to avoid nullpointers; last option then is if("t".equals(t_f)){